# error using render=>json

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have the following in my controller.
My requirement is to populate the second drop down based on the input from the 1st drop down.

```
def  update_releases 
 puts "inside func"
 project = Project.find(params[:project_id]) 
 @releases = project.releases
 puts "releases==#{releases}"
 render :json => @releases.map{|c| [c.id, c.name]} 
end
```

I am getting the error:

Started GET "/javascripts/jquery-ujs.js" for 172.30.11.164 at Thu Oct 20 14:22:06 +0530 2011

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/javascripts/jquery-ujs.js"):

Kindly help me out here.

Thanks,
Ramya.

Comment: It looks like your code isn't even running yet - you have a missing js file in your layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to include the file jquery-ujs.js which doesnt exist. Either you include a file that requires the jquery-ujs.js or you try it directly. Change your app/views/layout/application.html.erb and set the correct filename to include jquery.